# sonarqube 4.2 using clover for code coverage

Tags: sonarqube, clover

I am testing q Sonarqube 4.2 upgrade (currently on 3.6). I have so far been unable to get Sonar to use Clover for code coverage. There is now no option to set the coverage plugin (was under settings-> in 3.6) so I have set the property directly using -Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin on the maven build command for sonar.
Even so, the build logs has this entry
    - Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: /data/bamboo5.2.2-home/xml/build/APPCONFIGURATOR100-SONAR-JOB1/application-configurator/target/jacoco.exec
which implies that Jacoco is being used for coverage. The sonar build fails with the following error
    - [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project application-configurator: Can not execute Sonar: Can not add twice the same measure on org.sonar.api.resources.File@4095349b

What am I missing ? All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the version of the Java plugin ? The upcoming 2.2.1 version of Java plugin should take care of that issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm using version 2.2 of the Java plugin (sonar-java-plugin-2.2.jar). Is there a release date for the 2.2.1 version ?

Comment: The technical release is already done. Annoucement should follow.